# Edge weight in networkx

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, networkx, weighted-graph

How do I assign to each edge a weight equals to the number of times node i and j interacted from an edge list?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import scipy.sparse

df = pd.read_csv("thiers_2011.csv", header = None)
df = df.rename(columns={0: "t", 1: "id1", 2: "id2", 3: "C1", 4: "C2"})

edge_list = np.zeros((len(df),2))
edge_list[:,0] = np.array(df["id1"]) 
edge_list[:,1] = np.array(df["id2"]) 

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(edge_list)
```

Comment: First count the interactions and use add_weighted_edges_from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first aggregate the `pandas` tables to have a weight column, and then load it to `networkx` with that edge column:

```py
df["weight"] = 1.0
df = df.groupby([<id_columns>]).agg({"wight": sum}).reset_index()
```

To load it you can use also [`from_pandas_edgelist`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html):

```py
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(source='source_column', target='target_column', edge_attr="weight")
```